# Align multiple split-equation along different axis

Tags: equations, align, cases, split

I have some derivatives that I would to align along two axis; the first can be considered as the left border of the page, the `\partial/x..=` should align with the `cases`.

The second axis is on the right side, here the equal/notequal should align for all equations. Any ideas how todo that?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial QD} =  \\
&\begin{cases}
\frac{QB QD e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}+\frac{KoA}{QB}} -QBQD(e^{\frac{KoA}{QB}}-e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}})+QBKoA e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}}}{QD(QD e^{\frac{KoA}{QB}}-QB e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}})^2} 
&\forall ~QB\ne QD\\
\frac{KoA^2}{2(QD+KoA)^2}
&\forall ~QB= QD
\end{cases} \label{e:dkdqd}
\end{split} 
\\
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial KoA} = \\
&\begin{cases}\frac{(QD-QB)^2e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}+\frac{KoA}{QB}}}{(QBe^{KoA/QD}-QDe^{KoA/QB})^2} 
&\forall ~QB \neq QD\\
\frac{QD^2}{(QD+KoA)^2} 
&\forall ~QB = QD \label{e:dkdkoa}
\end{cases} 
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
& \frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial QB}= \\ 
& \begin{cases} \frac{(de^{k/b}(dbe^{k/b}+(k-d)e^{k/d}b-dke^{k/d}))}{(b(de^{k/b}-e^{k/d}b)^2)} 
&\forall ~QB \neq QD\\\
k^2/(2(d + k)^2)
&\forall ~QB= QD
\end{cases}
\end{split}
\label{e:dkdqb}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, excuse me. Into your MWE missing \documentclass.

Comment: @Sebastiano apologies, still struggling with the layouten

Comment: No apologies :-)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your requirements I propose this way:
 1. use `tabular` environment
 2. make containers `parbox` for equations
 3. use `eqnarray` to make link to equations

It's very far from ideal and fragile

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqnarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\parbox{4cm}{$$\frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial QD} =$$} & \\
\parbox{9cm}{$$\begin{cases}\frac{QB QD e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}+\frac{KoA}{QB}} -QBQD(e^{\frac{KoA}{QB}}-e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}})+QBKoA e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}}}{QD(QD e^{\frac{KoA}{QB}}-QB e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}})^2}\\ \frac{KoA^2}{2(QD+KoA)^2}\end{cases}$$} &
\parbox{3cm}{\begin{eqnarray}
    \forall ~QB\ne QD\\ \forall ~QB= QD\notag
    \label{e:dkdqd}\end{eqnarray}}\\
\parbox{4cm}{$$\frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial KoA} = $$} & \\
\parbox{5cm}{$$\begin{cases}\frac{(QD-QB)^2e^{\frac{KoA}{QD}+\frac{KoA}{QB}}}{(QBe^{KoA/QD}-QDe^{KoA/QB})^2}\\ \frac{QD^2}{(QD+KoA)^2}\end{cases}$$} &
\parbox{3cm}{\begin{eqnarray}
    \forall ~QB \neq QD\\ \forall ~QB = QD\notag
    \label{e:dkdkoa}\end{eqnarray}}\\
\parbox{4cm}{$$\frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial QB}=$$} & \\
\parbox{5cm}{$$\begin{cases}\frac{(de^{k/b}(dbe^{k/b}+(k-d)e^{k/d}b-dke^{k/d}))}{(b(de^{k/b}-e^{k/d}b)^2)} \\
k^2/(2(d + k)^2)\end{cases}$$} &
\parbox{3cm}{\begin{eqnarray}
    \forall ~QB \neq QD\\ \forall ~QB= QD\notag
    \label{e:dkdqb}\end{eqnarray}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Does it meet your expectations?

[image]

Comment: to the fullest, thank you a lot!